# Contact Form 7 validation : Border around input fields

Tags: jquery, wordpress, validation, contact-form-7

I am using contact form 7 plugin and I want to have border around text box.So for that I have changed `script.js` which is in `includes>JS` folder.

Before:

```
    $.fn.wpcf7NotValidTip = function(message) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var $into = $(this);

            $into.find('span.wpcf7-not-valid-tip').remove();
            $into.append('<span role="alert" class="wpcf7-not-valid-tip">' + message + '</span>');
            if ($into.is('.use-floating-validation-tip *')) {
                $('.wpcf7-not-valid-tip', $into).mouseover(function() {
                    $(this).wpcf7FadeOut();
                });

                $(':input', $into).focus(function() {
                    $('.wpcf7-not-valid-tip', $into).not(':hidden').wpcf7FadeOut();
                });
            }
        });
    };
```

After:

```
    $.fn.wpcf7NotValidTip = function(message) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var $into = $(this);

            $into.find('span.wpcf7-not-valid-tip').remove();
            $into.append('<span role="alert" class="wpcf7-not-valid-tip">' + message + '</span>');
            $into.find(':input').css('border-color', 'red');//it will add red color border
            if ($into.is('.use-floating-validation-tip *')) {
                $('.wpcf7-not-valid-tip', $into).mouseover(function() {
                    $(this).wpcf7FadeOut();
                    $into.find(':input').removeAttr('style'); //for removing red color
                });

                $(':input', $into).focus(function() {
                    $('.wpcf7-not-valid-tip', $into).not(':hidden').wpcf7FadeOut();
                    $into.find(':input').removeAttr('style');//for removind red color
                });
            }
        });
    };
```

**Issue** : At the time of validation it is showing validation.But I fill up the field, it should remove that border color.So how can I remove that color once I fill up all the things.So can anyone tell me what am I missing or what should I add ?

Comment: Why people are more interested in Down votes rather than giving solution ?
My question is pretty clear with what I want to achieve and I have provided code also..

Comment: Why editing .js? Can't you change the border with css? `border`, `box-shadow` and `outline` are the main 'culprits' when looking at input borders and such...

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner What does it mean ?

Comment: @dingo_d Actually I was not able to do it with CSS only cz validation is done through JS so I have to use JS to add CSS

Comment: That's weird, because I edited contact form 7s forms, and behavior without much problems in css :S Have you tried overwriting with `!important`?

Comment: Actually I have added extra fields and given my custom class.That's why.Have you been in this kind of prob ?Can you suggest me a way ?

Comment: Can you provide fiddle or link?

Comment: It was not for you ..I was posting somewhere else but by mistake posted here.
Can you give more code like for `wpcf7FadeOut();`?Or else We need to download plugin to check :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through the plugin for almost an hour found the solution.

You are removing your **style** at **wrong place**.

```
$.fn.wpcf7NotValidTip = function(message) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var $into = $(this);

        $into.find('span.wpcf7-not-valid-tip').remove();
        $into.append('<span role="alert" class="wpcf7-not-valid-tip">' + message + '</span>');
        $into.find(':input').css('border-color', 'red');//it will add red color border
        if ($into.is('.use-floating-validation-tip *')) {
            $('.wpcf7-not-valid-tip', $into).mouseover(function() {
                $(this).wpcf7FadeOut();
                //removed this line from your code
            });

            $(':input', $into).focus(function() {
                $('.wpcf7-not-valid-tip', $into).not(':hidden').wpcf7FadeOut();
                //removed this line from your code
            });
        }
    });
};
```

You need to remove your style in `wpcf7ClearResponseOutput` this function:

```
    $.fn.wpcf7ClearResponseOutput = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).find('div.wpcf7-response-output').hide().empty().removeClass('wpcf7-mail-sent-ok wpcf7-mail-sent-ng wpcf7-validation-errors wpcf7-spam-blocked').removeAttr('role');
            $(this).find('span.wpcf7-not-valid-tip').remove();
            $(this).find(':input').removeAttr('style'); //here I have added those lines for removing style
            $(this).find('img.ajax-loader').css({ visibility: 'hidden' });
        });
    };
```

Hope it works for you.Great task for me :)

Comment: Wow!! You managed in just hour and I was trying for like 5 hours :)
It worked like gem.Thanks:)